# Random error SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection is closed

Tags: hibernate, mariadb, wildfly-10, wildfly-swarm, deltaspike

From time to time we get the following error in our Wildfly Swarm app server (full stack trace at the end):

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=19796385) Connection is closed
```

Can someone explain how these kind of errors can occur? Why doesn't my persistence layer just create another connection but instead throw this error? The error is totally random and I don't know how to debug this.

I'm guessing that either:

- My Hibernate configuration is wrong (do I have to use connection pooling to prevent these errors?)
- MariaDB Java Client does something wrong
- We are using DeltaSpike Data for simplifying our
  repository layer. Maybe there is a problem here? (see configuration
  below)

**Server Details**

- Wildfly Swarm: 2018.4.1
- mariadb-java-client: 2.2.3
- deltaspike-data: 1.8.0

**Wildfly Swarm DataSource Configuration:**

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      xyzAppDS:
        driver-name: mariadb
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker
        validate-on-match: true
        background-validation: false
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter
```

**Hibernate (persistence.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            version="2.1"
            xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="xyzAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
            <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/xyzAppDS</jta-data-source>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value=""/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

**DeltasSpike Data Configuration (apache-deltaspike.properties):**

```
globalAlternatives.org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.spi.transaction.TransactionStrategy=org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ContainerManagedTransactionStrategy
```

**EntityManagerProducer for DeltaSpike Data**

```
public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceContext
    @Produces
    private EntityManager entityManager;

}
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.builder.result.QueryProcessorFactory$ListQueryProcessor.executeQuery(QueryProcessorFactory.java:107)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.CdiQueryInvocationContext.executeQuery(CdiQueryInvocationContext.java:241)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.builder.AnnotatedQueryBuilder.execute(AnnotatedQueryBuilder.java:53)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.builder.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(QueryBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.builder.AnnotatedQueryBuilder$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.tx.TransactionalQueryRunner.executeNonTransactional(TransactionalQueryRunner.java:66)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.tx.TransactionalQueryRunner.executeQuery(TransactionalQueryRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.tx.TransactionalQueryRunner$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.process(QueryHandler.java:147)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:129)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.deltaspike.proxy.impl.invocation.DelegateManualInvocationHandler.proceedOriginal(DelegateManualInvocationHandler.java:47)
at org.apache.deltaspike.proxy.impl.invocation.AbstractManualInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractManualInvocationHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.deltaspike.proxy.impl.invocation.DelegateManualInvocationHandler$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.deltaspike.proxy.impl.invocation.DelegateManualInvocationHandler.staticInvoke(DelegateManualInvocationHandler.java:40)
at com.xyzApp.db.repository.PatientNeedRepository$$DSPartialBeanProxy.findIdsForNoOpenNotification(Unknown Source)
at com.xyzApp.business.escalation.EscalationService.escalatePatientNeeds(EscalationService.java:38)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor464.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:92)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.interceptorChainCompleted(WeldInvocationContext.java:98)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.proceed(WeldInvocationContext.java:117)
at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInCallerTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:132)
at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:55)
at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:79)
at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor437.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContext.java:83)
at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.proceed(WeldInvocationContext.java:115)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:108)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.delegateInterception(EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.java:60)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:88)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255)
... 111 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2122)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1905)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1980)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
... 169 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=19796385) Connection is closed
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:175)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:216)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:164)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
... 184 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.cmdPrologue(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1706)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:236)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:209)
... 188 more
```

Comment: are you having `c3p0` like connection pooling component?

Comment: is this error coming after some idle time, say 8 hours?

Comment: Exactly, if you are not using any connection pooling then you have to check `wait_timeout`, `connection_timeout` of DB.

Comment: @naren We actually have an EJB Scheduler running that queries the database every 5 minutes.... so there will never be any idle time.

Comment: @Amogh Do you still think `wait_timeout` and `connection_timeout` could be relevant even though we do a scheduled query every 5 minutes? How could there be any idle time?

Comment: @MichaelHunziker If in case a query is running for long time then yes its relevant? is it a multi-threaded?

Comment: @MichaelHunziker is there a possibility that scheduler is running on a different node (usually we fix the node to run scheduled tasks). Also you are using MySQLDialect. Can you change it to MariaDBDialect based on your version of db as those are available now?

Comment: One more question: does every query fails when you encounter the problem or just some selected queries? And how you get rid of the problem, restart?

Comment: Hibernate supports connection url. Connection url can have
"sessionVariables=wait_timeout=1000000" in the URL query string

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll try your suggestions with the connection pool and the MariaDBDialect

Comment: @Amogh: Again I'm not sure if I really have to use third party connection pooling. According to this discussion every JavaEE server should provide connection pooling. We are using Wildfly Swarm 2018.5 (= Wildfly 11):

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241174